# Apache 2.4 hanging when 404 is returned from backend

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, apache-2.4

I have a backend server and apache2 as frontend, it's configured to show a custom 404 page but when backend returns 404 apache starts hanging. It works fine when 404 is generated on apache side. Here's the config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /somepath

        ErrorLog /somepath/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /somepath/logs/access.log combined

        ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

        ProxyPass /dir1 !
        ProxyPass /dir2 !
        ProxyPass /backend balancer://cluster/
        ProxyPassReverse /backend balancer://cluster/
        <Proxy balancer://cluster>
                BalancerMember http://localhost:7777
                ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
        </Proxy>
        ProxyErrorOverride On

</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

In addition, logs don't report about any issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found this is a bug in Apache 2.4 in ProxyErrorOverride
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53420